# Replacement for getTypeId()

Tags: bukkit

I made a plugin for bukkit 1.2.5 (to used on a tekkit server) that alerted players when someone (for example) tried to place down some tnt which is why I using block IDs.

Now that I'm trying to use an updated version of bukkit (1.7.2-R0.3 to be exact) it seems that the getTypeId() method is no longer working. I've googling/searching in the javadoc for a solution but I can't find one.

```
// Checks if the block placed has the id of 46 / tnt
        if (e.getBlock().getTypeId() == 46) {
            e.setCancelled(true);
            Server server = Bukkit.getServer();
            server.broadcastMessage("Someone tried to place some tnt down");
        }
```

How do I get it to work in 1.7.2 now that getTypeId() is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the `getTypeId()` method for Blocks or the `getId()` method for the Block `Material` despite the fact that they are deprecated. If you add the @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") annotation to your listener method your IDE should not complain about using the deprecated methods. You can also alternatively use the non-deprecated `Material` enum directly with `event.getBlock().getType() == Material.TNT`.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to be working. Can you look at my code? I haven't changed anything but the part that I posted in the main question.

AntiBlock.java: http://www.codesend.com/view/fcc56dc694bd3144531fe477f150fed2/

BlockListener.java: http://www.codesend.com/view/df6b3b8de7f6735b609f31e7f138628b/

plugin.yml:
http://www.codesend.com/view/7bba0e7fdb8cdfaa0ed844829ea7a3ef/

Comment: Tried to see what part is wrong so I modified the BlockListener.java: http://www.codesend.com/view/d6b041203acc12d13df8d4d390d20415/

Comment: Exported the latest version of my plugin for 1.2.5-R4 and it still works, so I just copied the old code, changed the getTypeId() with getType() as your answer says and it still doesn't work. The Code for 1.2.5: AntiBlock.java => http://www.codesend.com/view/1ddf9255d7e944836c4e76c20a88ef3a/ BlockListener.java => http://www.codesend.com/view/948b3cce2f6d99e6e9f6e187a34850f0/ The Code for 1.7.2: AntiBlock.java => http://www.codesend.com/view/67252f6606603f76b9d84f2f0cf939b3/ BlockListener.java => http://www.codesend.com/view/d0daab47f493309618457ba622e1aaae/